# Focus switch in TKinter widgets not working programmatically

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, focus

I have TKinter app with a window with just two widgets: a `Listbox` and an Entry. Now, I want that whenever a user click on an item in the `Listbox`, the focus switch immediately to the Entry. But neither `Entry.focus_set()` nor `Entry.focus_force()` are working. Is there a way to make it work?

```
lb = Listbox(root)
lb.pack()
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', sel_done)
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()


def sel_done():
    entry.focus_set()
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues I see are:

- Binding to `'<<ListboxSelect>>'` will trigger the event callback `sel_done` when the mouse button is *pressed*, but then the `Listbox` will take focus as soon as the mouse button is *released*.  To fix this, you can instead bind to `'<ButtonRelease>'`

```
lb.bind('<ButtonRelease>', sel_done)
```

- The event binding automatically passes an `event` argument to the bound function, so either `sel_done` will need to accept this argument (even if you're not using it) *or* you can absorb it using a `lambda` (an anonymous function)

**OPTION ONE** - have `sel_done` accept the extra argument

```
# you can call this parameter whatever you like, but typically "event" is used
# and the leading _underscore implies that this value is ignored/unused
def sel_done(_event):
    entry.focus_set()  # FWIW, you can also just use 'focus()'
```

**OPTION TWO** - use a `lambda` in the event binding itself

```
# note the () after 'sel_done' - this is because we're actually binding to an
# anonymous function, and then telling *that* function to call 'sel_done()';
# the _event arg is "absorbed" by the lambda and can be safely ignored
lb.bind('<ButtonRelease>', lambda _event: sel_done())
```

Comment: That's it! It worked quite nicely!!! Tnx a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to help. If this worked for you, please mark this answer as "Accepted" so that others know this question has been answered. That said, I'd encourage you to take a deeper look at Byran Okaley's answer as they almost* always know more than I do. (*hedging bets here)

Answer (score 1):

When you bind a function to an event, that function must accept a parameter. Yours doesn't, so it's throwing an error when the callback is triggered.

The other problem is that the listbox itself has bindings that manage the focus on button release. To work around this, you can request that the focus be changed after the event loop has gone idle (ie: after the listbox has finished processing the events).

Putting those together, your function should look like this:

```
def sel_done(event):
    entry.after_idle(entry.focus_set)
```

Comment: I always forget about `after_idle`! Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, but it didn't work.

Comment: @angico: it works fine for me when I add just enough code to make the code you posted into a complete program.